# after running insert or update query, need the last inserted record and compare in vb.net sql server

Tags: vb.net, insert

i have 2 queries in vb.net with an if clause -
if x=0 then
insert into table1
else
update table1

both queries have 5 fields. now what i want to do is after this insert or update takes place, i need to look at this inserted/updated record and compare it with another table (table2). Especially for update, i have 5 fields in both tables. if any of the 5 fields dont match with table2, then i insert a new record in table 2 which is the updated record in table 1.
how can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx?ppud=4) and keep this all on the database.